# System.Windows.Data Error: 5 ; FontSizeConverter is causing Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am struggling with this Error N°5. Here is the complete Error Message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
> not valid for target property.; Value='0'
> BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem='Grid'
> (Name='gridEingabemaske'); target element is 'TextBox'
> (Name='txtabmessungStecknuss'); target property is 'FontSize' (type
> 'Double')

Here is what I have figured out so far:
I have a WPF-Control, which hosts a lot of Textboxes (118 to be specific). I also use a FontSizeConverter to manipulate the FontSize in the Textboxes. This FontSizeConverter seems to cause the Problem, because it expects a Double-Value but gets a 0 (Integer) instead.

How can I fix this?

my xaml-code (just give you  1 of 118 Textboxes at the End):

```
<UserControl x:Class="SchrauberDB.Controls.Eingabemaske"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SchrauberDB.View"
         xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:SchrauberDB.DataModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="1100"
         FontFamily="Arial">

<UserControl.Resources>

    <dm:FontSizeConverter x:Key="fontSizeCon" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="50"/>

            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0 ,0" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />

                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6A767D" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="160" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6A767D" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C2CACF" />

    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="gridEingabemaske" Background="#FEFFFF" >

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" 
            Height="45" Width="160">
        <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium">
            Speichern
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" 
            Height="45" Width="160" Click="Button_CreateBemi_Click" 
            >
        <TextBlock  FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium">
            Neues Bemi Anlegen
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>

    <ListView x:Name="lvEingabe" Margin="25" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>

    <StackPanel x:Name="abmessungStecknuss" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock>Abmessung Stecknuss</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtabmessungStecknuss" Text="{Binding Path=abmessungStecknuss}" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeCon}}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    
    ...
```

And here´s my FontSizeConverter Class:

```
namespace SchrauberDB.DataModel
{
    public class FontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double actualHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            int fontSize = (int)(actualHeight * .05);
            return fontSize;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you perform explicit cast to int? `return actualHeight * .05;`

Comment: I have tried your approach but it didn´t work. I still get the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast from `double` to `int` is redundant. You should remove it. Furthermore, don't throw a `NotImplementedException` exception. If the `ConvertBack` method is not supported, then throw the `NotSupportedException`.

The problem here is that, according to the error message, the value for the ActualHeight is `0`. While `0` is a valid height, it is an illegal value for the `FontSize`.

The message:

*"Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target"*
Then it states that the value is
*"Value='0'"*
The target is
*"target element is 'TextBox'"*
The target property
*"target property is 'FontSize'"*

The message is clealy communicating an invalid **value** and not an invalid **type**!
The error message translates to: "The value `0` is not valid for the `TextBox.FontSize` property."

Equipped with this knowledge, you now consult the API reference for the [`Control.FontSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#property-value) property. From here you learn:

> The font size must be a positive number.

From our Math class we know that zero is not a positive number.
Problem identified. Solution is obvious: prevent illegal converter values.

This means, you should add some robustness to your converter implementation:

```cs
public class FontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    double actualHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
    double fontSize = actualHeight * .05;
    return Math.Max(0.1, fontSize);

    // Alternatively return a default value e.g., 12
    return fontsize == 0 ? 12 : fontsize
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: it works... thank you!